# NodeJs troubleshooting hanging console

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJs App which is getting bigger and bigger as time goes on. In the beginning i used the console.log a lot to debug in development to see if and what went wrong. More often i am now faced with a stuck app which does not process until i hit the enter key on my keyboard while in the console. So i started to remove as much of the console.log usage, the only other stuff i have is i am running morgan so i can see what requests come in and if we return a 2xx code etc.
So what causes the console to get stuck sometimes , how can i track down the source and how do i eliminate this all together ?

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yes it is Windows 64 Bit

Comment: On `cmd` I presume? If so, `cmd` has a weird behavior where if you click or select (with your mouse) any portion of the console, it stops processing! To test this, open `cmd` go to the root of your C drive and issue a `dir /s` command. While files are being listed on the screen, click anywhere on the console, and you'll see that execution stops, and you'll have to press enter to continue! Suggestions: Use the new Terminal app (from Microsoft Store), or use PowerShell.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701

Comment: Interesting, as my Server is not local i use Terminal Server to remotely connect to it and then watch the console i started the NodeJs process in. I was able to recreate the issue by clicking into the console window and all process stopped, pressing enter in console window resumes the process

Comment: Yep, it's an annoying quirk. Again, I think PowerShell doesn't have this problem, if that's at all a possibility.

Comment: Some more conversation about this CMD behavior here: https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd

Comment: Notably, your process continues in the background until the next time it needs to write to console. So, back to your question, if you remove absolutely all console outputs from your application, you may avert this situation, but then at that point, what's the point of keeping the terminal open.

Comment: Final thought, consider using PM2 to run your server. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Comment: But as i use morgan which logs to console every request there is realy nothing that will be processed until i hit enter again

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path, i originally thought my code was the issue but it seems to be good all Windows / Microsoft. Since i need some ODBC drivers i have no other choice for now. As Windows Terminal is in Alpha and you cant download it i found another workaround. I downloaded Git Bash. I can start my App and even if i click on console it no longer stops process